# How to mock an object from interface?

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Given an interface in typescript, can I automatically mock out of it a new object with dummy values instead of manually writing an object?

Let's take for example the following `interface`:

```
interface SquareConfig {
    color: string;
    width: number;
}
```

I would like to have a mock object which implements the interface properties, e.g:

```
const mockConfig = jest.mock<SquareConfig>();
console.log(mockConfig.color); //should print some auto-generated dummy string value
```

Is it possible in some way?

Comment: You can take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fluffy-spoon/substitute